Mostrar Raiserror de SQL en dialog de windows forms C#
Estoy haciendo mi primer aplicación en Windows Forms con C# y SQL Server, tengo una duda que posiblemente para muchos sea algo sencillo, espero me puedan ayudar.
Necesito saber si existe alguna forma de capturar el error que se muestra en mi stored procedure cuando no se cumple alguna condición y mostrarla en un label o un dialog de windows forms.
RAISERROR (N'Este es el error que deseo mostrar en el label. %s %d.',
           10, 
           1, 
           N'number',
           5);

Estoy usando la arquitectura en capas.
Este es el C#
Capa datos
       cmd.Connection = conn;
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.CommandText = ("xp_ValidaSesion");
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empresa", empresa);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Encrypt.GetSHA256(password));
       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       if (reader.HasRows) {
           }
           return true;
          
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }

Capa Negocio:
 public class UsuarioModel
 {
     UsuarioDao usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();
     public bool LoginUsuario(String usuario, String password, string empresa)
     {
         return usuarioDao.Login(usuario, password, empresa);
     }

Capa presentacion:
 private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (TxtUsuario.Text != "" && TxtPassword.Text != "" && CbxEmpresa.ValueMember != "")
     {
         UsuarioModel usuario =  new UsuarioModel();
         var LoginValido = usuario.LoginUsuario(TxtUsuario.Text, TxtPassword.Text, CbxEmpresa.SelectedValue.ToString());
         if(LoginValido == true)
         {
             MainForm mainView = new MainForm();
             mainView.Show();
             this.Hide();
         }
         else
         {

             msgError("Fallo la conexión. Por favor valide sus datos.");
             TxtPassword.Clear();
             TxtUsuario.Focus();
         }
     }
     else {
         msgError("No puede haber campos vacios.");
     }
 }

Pero lo que quiero lograr es mostrar errores personalizados por cada validacion, es decir si el usuario existe pero la contraseña es incorrecta mostrar un error, si el usuario existe pero esta inactivo mostrar un error distinto.
Saludos, espero me puedan orientar.

Probas un try/catch?

No, como podría hacerlo, ya actualice mi pregunta con el codigo c# que tengo. Me puedes ayudar por favor.

Usas un try/catch, la excepción la levanta  SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); pero se propaga, pudiendo colocarlo en otro lugar del código, por ejemplo:
 private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (TxtUsuario.Text != "" && TxtPassword.Text != "" && CbxEmpresa.ValueMember != "")
     {
         UsuarioModel usuario =  new UsuarioModel();

         try{
             var LoginValido = usuario.LoginUsuario(TxtUsuario.Text, TxtPassword.Text, CbxEmpresa.SelectedValue.ToString());

             if(LoginValido == true)
             {
                MainForm mainView = new MainForm();
                mainView.Show();
                this.Hide();
             }
             else
             {
                msgError("Login no valido");
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             msgError(ex.Message); //ex.Menssage contiene el mensaje seteado en la base de datos
         }
     }
     else {
         msgError("No puede haber campos vacios.");
     }
 }


Ya lo intente como sugeriste, pero pasa que si ocurre un error del tipo que sea muestra de inmediato Login no valido  pienso que sucede porque el if es la primer validación antes de entrar al catch, ¿Sabes que estoy haciendo mal?

No entra en el catch porque un error de severidad 10 no se considera realmente un error sino un mensaje informativo. Cambia la severidad a 16: RAISERROR (N'Este es el error que deseo mostrar en el label. %s %d.', 16, 1, N'number', 5); Severity

Perfecto, con eso funciono a la perfección. Muchas Gracias.
